# ERROR in src/app/pages/patients/wigs/waiting/waiting.component.ts(36,25): error TS2339: Property 'addWaiting' does not exist on type 'WaitingService'

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried for add a `Mat Dialog` into my `waiting` component by referring a video in you tube. I think I had followed the steps correctly. But there is a this sort of error .

```
ERROR in src/app/pages/patients/wigs/waiting/waiting.component.ts(36,25): error TS2339: Property 'addWaiting' does not exist on type 'WaitingService'.
```

I will show you my files which are belongs to `waiting` component.

**waiting.component.html**

```
<mat-card-header>
  <mat-toolbar class="toolbar">
    <mat-card-title>contact information</mat-card-title>
    <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
    <mat-icon (click)="onNoClick()">cancel</mat-icon>
  </mat-toolbar>
</mat-card-header>

<mat-card-content>
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="waitingForm" (submit)="onSubmit()"></form>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input text="text" formControlname="FirstName" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input text="text" formControlname="LastName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Contact Number:</label>
        <input text="text" formControlname="Contack" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input text="text" formControlname="Email" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess">
        <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</mat-card-content>
```

**waiting.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Waiting } from './waiting.model';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WaitingService {
    waitingList: Waiting[] = [];

    constructor(private database: AngularFirestore) {}

    addWaiting(waiting: Waiting) {
        this.waitingList.push(waiting);
    }

    removeWaiting(id: number) {
        const waiting = this.waitingList.findIndex(c => c.ID === id);
        this.waitingList.splice(waiting, 1);
    }

    getAllWaiting() {
        return this.waitingList;
    }
}
```

**waiting.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { WaitingService } from './waiting.service';

@Component({
selector: 'ngx-waiting',
templateUrl: './waiting.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./waiting.component.scss']
})
export class WaitingComponent implements OnInit {
    public waitingForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<WaitingComponent>,
        private waitingService: WaitingService,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
    ) {}

    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.waitingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        ID: [],
        FirstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        LastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        contact: ['', [Validators.required]],
        Email: ['', [Validators.required]]
        });
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.waitingService.addWaiting(this.waitingForm.value);   
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

**waiting.model.ts**

```
export class Waiting {
    ID: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    contact: string;
    Email: string;
}
```

This is the problem. So what should I do.

Comment: Provide Stackblitz if possible because by looking at your code all looks fine for me

Comment: can you show us coming `waiting` obeject

Comment: My guess is that you have several different waiting services. Also, please respect the naming conventions and be consistent. All the properties of Waiting should start with a lowercase letter. The inconsistencies will become a major pain for yourself once the app grows.

Comment: @ram12393  `waiting` came from  `addWaiting(waiting: Waiting) `  function in `waiting.service.ts`